# React lazy recursive import

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-lazy-load

I have requirement where I need to load component from dynamic folders. For example I have following folders inside components

```
components  
    -default
        -component-one
        -component-two
        -component-three
    -custom
        -component-three
```

Suppose if `componentFolder state` set to `custom` folder then it should load from `custom folder` .if any component not found in `custom folder` then it should be load from `default` folder.
So my question is ,can we possible to import recursively ?

```
 function App() {
 
const [componentFolder, setComponentFolder] = React.useState("default")

const Home = React.lazy(() => import("./components/" +componentFolder+ "/Home"));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense fallback="laoding">
        <Home></Home>
      
      </Suspense>

    </div>
  );
}
```

the below link has same requirement as i asked
[How to check if a pariticular fileExists in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259512/how-to-check-if-a-pariticular-fileexists-in-reactjs/48264153)

Comment: @ajeet thanks for mentioning...but one point helped regarding rerender

Comment: Is this a CRA project?

Comment: Note : bounty question expires in 2 hours so giving bounty to  one of the below answers for their effort .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Webpack then you can use [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext) to load modules dynamically:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

const load = async (path, file) => {
  const defaultPath = "default";
  const files = require.context("./components", true, /\.js$/);
  try {
    return files(`./${path}/${file}.js`);
  } catch (err) {
    return files(`./${defaultPath}/${file}.js`);
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const [componentFolder, setComponentFolder] = React.useState("default");
  const Home = React.lazy(() => load(componentFolder, "Home"));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense fallback="loading">
        <Home />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @lissettdm.thanks for the answer .i am not using reactjs using create react app.i am not sure its webpack or not.since i am beginner to reactjs .

Comment: What module bundler are you using? can you check that?

Comment: i sorry my previous comment has wrong typo.I am using reactjs using create react app https://create-react-app.dev/.Also  i am okay with different solution other than lazy loading if my requirement satisfies

Comment: CRA use Webpack as module bundle. You can use require.context to load modules dynamically and you can combine it with Lazy load

Answer (score 2):

Since [`lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactlazy) returns a promise, you can use its `catch` block to return another `lazy` (promise) when the original module was not found.

**An example:**

```
import { lazy, Suspense, useState } from "react";

const rotate = {
  custom: "default",
  default: "custom",
};

function App() {
  const [folder, setFolder] = useState("custom");
  const [name, setName] = useState("component1");

  // Here: catch and return another lazy (promise)

  const Component = lazy(() =>
    import("./components/" + folder + "/" + name).catch(
      (err) => import("./components/" + rotate[folder] + "/" + name)
    )
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback="laoding">
        <Component />
      </Suspense>
      <button onClick={() => setFolder(rotate[folder])}>toggle folder</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setName("component1")}>load component 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setName("component2")}>load component 2</button>
      <button onClick={() => setName("component3")}>load component 3</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-lazy-load-ot9ej).

---

Note that `Component`, defined/created inside `App` component, will be **recreated** at every rerender of `App`. [It will cause Component to *reset* its state when App rerenders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66571922/2873538).

Comment: thanks but i am looking for recursive since it might be multiple parent child hierarchy so .For example default->custom->client-specific then it will first check in client -specific then it will check in custom then its go to default .is there any solution's will try this anyway

Comment: Hm. I thought you wrote "recursive" by mistake as I saw no recursive path in your example.

Comment: @ajeeh.yes i have tried many methods but couldn't succeeded so .even other solution other than lazy loading also fine.thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1):

Based in the others answers and comments here I came up with this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-react-lazy-recursive-import-2dqlp?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";

// test the code by removing the _ in front of file names

/*
components/
  comp  3? a root file will not trigger -> go to default
  
  /default
    comp  3! nice ^^ (but if it not exists will throw an error)

  /custom
    comp  2?
    /client
      comp  1?
        /omgStop
          heIsAlreadyDead (but works)
    /otherClient ...
*/

const recursiveImport = async (
  componentName,
  targetTree,
  defaultTree = "./components/default"
) => {
  console.count("paths tested");
  if (!targetTree) {
    return import(defaultTree + "/" + componentName);
  }

  return import("./components/" + targetTree + "/" + componentName).catch(
    () => {
      const newTreeArr = targetTree.split("/");
      newTreeArr.pop();
      const newTree = newTreeArr.join("/");
      return recursiveImport(componentName, newTree, defaultTree);
    }
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const targetTree = "custom/client1";
  const Component = lazy(() => recursiveImport("Test", targetTree));

  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback="loading">{<Component />}</Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Folder structure:

[image]

This solves all of your requirements?

Comment: Note : bounty question expires in 2 hours so giving bounty to one of the below answers for their effort .i  will try this soon and let you know .

Answer (score 0):

Simple and objective

```
const Recipe = React.lazy(() =>
  import(`docs/app/Recipes/${props.componentName}`)
  .catch(() => ({ default: () => <div>Not found</div> }))
);
```

Answer (score -2):

I was trying something, endup with a simple solution that you should reach before:

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-violet-fr7np?file=/src/App.js