# Don't display next/image component when the image doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm using next/image and I want the image to not render at all when the path to the image is invalid, eg. the image doesn't exist. Now it displays the little icon and alt name. I don't want to display anything in that case. Is that possible? Since it's frontend I can't use `fs` to check, so I'm not sure what to do

```
      <Image
         src={`/scroll-${router.locale}.svg`}
         alt="scroll"
         width="240px"
         height="240px"
         className="opacity-50"
       />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a pariticular fileExists in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259512/how-to-check-if-a-pariticular-fileexists-in-reactjs)

Comment: You need to look inside the component to see if it's looking for `onerror` - if it is you can use something like `onerror="this.style.display='none'"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can extend the built-in `next/image` and add an `onError` handler to not render the component if the image fails to load.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';

const ImageWithHideOnError = (props) => {
    const [hideImage, setHideImage] = useState(false);

    return (
        !hideImage && (
            <Image
               {...props}
               onError={() => {
                   setHideImage(true);
               }}
            />
        )
    );
};

export default ImageWithHideOnError;
```

You can then use the component instead of the `next/image`.

```js
<ImageWithHideOnError
    src={`/scroll-${router.locale}.svg`}
    alt="scroll"
    width="240px"
    height="240px"
    className="opacity-50"
/>
```